# How to Filter object and get certain field in Javascript

Tags: javascript, filter

I'm struggle with using filter.

**Initial object**
This is my object.

```
[{
  isOpen : true,
  items : [
    {itemId : '', name : 'some name'},
    {itemId : 'new', name : 'new name'}
  ]
},]
```

**Expected Result**

I just want to show that the `itemId` is not an empty string and also `isOpen` field.

```
[{
  isOpen : true,
  items : [
    {itemId : 'new', name : 'new name'}
  ]
},]
```

---

**What I try**

```
  const removeEmptyStringInItems = (item) => item.items?.filter((v) => v.itemId);
  const finalItems = myItems.map(removeEmptyStringInItems);
```

**output**.

```
{itemId : 'new', name : 'new name'}
```

Any ideas for this problem? I really need help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could try update the code to this to keep the finalItems format same as the initial value

```
const removeEmptyStringInItems = (items = []) => items?.filter((v) => v.itemId);
const finalItems = myItems.map((v) => ({...v, items: removeEmptyStringInItems(v.items)}));
```